# $C$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ of cardinality $|C| = n$. Show that $|\sigma(C)| \leq 2^{2^n}$

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, cardinals

The question is the following:

> For an arbitrary set $\Omega$, assume that $\mathcal{C}$  is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ of cardinality $|\mathcal{C}| = n$. Show that $|\sigma(\mathcal{C}) |\leq 2^{2^n}$

Also, there is a provided hint saying that

> Assume first that the events in $\mathcal{C}$ are disjoint and cover $\Omega$.

and I can't get this hint. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Double-check the problem.  It currently doesn't make any sense, and I believe it should be asking $$|\sigma(\mathcal{C})| \leq 2^{2^n}$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right!! Thanks for the correction!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{C} = \{C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_n\}.$  Then there are at most $2^n$ sets of the form 
$$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n$$
where $A_i$ is either $C_i$ or $\Omega\setminus C_i.$  Importantly, these sets are disjoint, they cover $\Omega,$ and the [sigma] algebra generated by them is $\sigma(\mathcal{C}).$ **[You should show all three of these points, none should take long]**

For practical reasons, let's collect these $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ into a new set $$\mathcal{B} = \{B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_m\}$$
where we have noted that $m\leq 2^n,$ the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint and cover $\Omega,$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{B}) = \sigma(\mathcal{C}).$  Further, we may assume $\emptyset \not\in \mathcal{B},$ as this won't change $\sigma(\mathcal{B}).$

Now I'll leave it to you to show that in this scenario (where $\mathcal{B}$ is a partition of $\Omega$) the elements of $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$ are unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}.$  That is, **you need to show** $$X \in \sigma(\mathcal{B}) \iff \exists I \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,m\} \text{ such that } X = \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$$

This allows us to conclude $$|\sigma(\mathcal{C})| = |\sigma(\mathcal{B})| = 2^m \leq 2^{2^n}$$

Comment: I assume that you assumed the events in $\mathcal{C}$ are disjoint and cover $\Omega$? It is clear that $B_i$ are disjoint, but how they cover $\Omega$ while being disjoint? Does it even make sense? Or do you mean that the union of them covers $\Omega$.

Comment: The only assumptions I made about $\mathcal{C}$ is that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $|\mathcal{C}| = n$ (i.e. what is given in the problem statement).  By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)), we say a collections of sets $\mathcal{V}$ covers a set $X$ when $X$ is a subset of the union, i.e. $X \subseteq \bigcup_{V\in \mathcal{V}}V.$  That is, in our context, that $\mathcal{B}$ covers $\Omega$ just means $$\Omega = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \ldots \cup B_m$$ (we can use equality instead of subset since the union is obviously a subset of $\Omega$)